# Better way of looping through form inputs?

Tags: php, html

I have a form with inputs that can be dynamically added with a button click. The name/id of these inputs are setup to take advantage of arrays in PHP (read about this trick), but I don't prefer this method because it just doesn't feel right and because I wanted to do it how I originally thought of, but encountered issues when I tried. I could use some guidance because I'm over-thinking this. This is what I have at the moment...

**HTML**

```
<input name="specs[1][number]" id="specs[1][number]" type="text" placeholder="Specs..." />
```

**PHP**

```
$specCounter = count($_POST[specs]);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $specCounter; $i++) {

    echo '<li>' . $_POST[specs][$i][number] . '</li>';

};
```

As you can see, it's pretty straight forward; I have an array called specs and the value of the input will eventually be placed into the number slot.

But what I originally wanted, was something like this:

**HTML**

```
<input name="specs1" id="specs1" type="text" placeholder="Specs..." />
<input name="specs2" id="specs2" type="text" placeholder="Specs..." />
```

The problem I'm having is looping through these in PHP, because I don't know how to get a count of these inputs...

**PHP**

```
var myTotal = 'total inputs that have specs in the name/id';

for (var i = 1; i < myTotal; i++) {
    echo $_POST['specs' . i];
};
```

At the time of this writing, it dawned on me that maybe I should explore regular expressions, but maybe not? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To get a count you would use ummm... `count()`.  I would use `foreach()` to loop though.

Comment: But your first way using arrays is the way I would go, though simply with just `spec[1]` etc...

Comment: Better to write `$_POST["specs"][$i]["number"]` or `$_POST['specs'][$i]['number']` than `$_POST[specs][$i][number]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
while(isset($_POST['specs'.$i]))
{
    echo $_POST['specs'.$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Also another way to put this:

```
for($i=1; isset($_POST['specs'.$i]); $i++) 
{
    echo $_POST['specs'.$i];
}
```

Whichever you prefer

Or if your numbers are not continuous:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($key) === 'specs') {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shorter with while(isset($_POST['specs'.$i]))

Comment: Or with for: for($i = 1; isset($_POST['specs'.$i]); $i++) echo $_POST['specs'.$i];

Comment: that's just realization. I don't think, personally, it looks any clearer or takes less space

Comment: I like this because it doesn't require knowing the count and will output all of them as long as the first one is set, which it should be.

Comment: Upon further review, wouldn't this loop forever and isn't that a bad thing?

Comment: of course not! As soon as `$i` becomes large enough, there will be no `$_POST['specsN` large enough and that moment the loop will be broken.

Comment: Any of those loop are infinite. No bad pratice here. Test and try to see the loop step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($key) === 'specs') {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good because it acknowledged my intent of looking for specific text in a name/id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `foreach` instead a `for`:

```
foreach($_POST[specs] as $spec) {
    echo '<li>' . $spec['number'] . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way using arrays is normally preferred.  I would simplify it though:

**HTML**

```
<input name="specs[1]" type="text"..." />
<input name="specs[2]" type="text"..." />
```

**PHP**

```
foreach($_POST['specs'] as $key => $val) {
    echo "specs $key is $val";
}
```

Unless you need them, you don't even have to specify the indexes, they will be created automagically:

```
<input name="specs[]" type="text"..." />
<input name="specs[]" type="text"..." />
```

Comment: he does know about `[ ]` variant. Read the original post.